# daily incremental results on table where transaction date <= @Date parameter

Tags: sql

specifically looking for General Leger results. This means that I can't sum up transactions for specfic dates, or cant run Between date.

to get the results for say, today I would need to query the table for all transactions <= @Today.

That said, i am tasked with running this for every single day in 2020 thus far. is there a method to do this where i dont have to manually run for each day myself?

Query example:

```
glo.GLValue
, Sum(UnitCR) AS 'Credit'
, Sum(UnitDR) AS 'Debit'
, sum(FirmCR) AS 'FirmCredit' 
, sum(FirmDR) AS 'FirmDebit' 
FROM glacct ga
inner join gldetail gd on gd.glacct = ga.AcctIndex
inner join glnatural gn on ga.glnatural = gn.GLNaturalID
inner join glunit glu on ga.glunit = glu.GLUnitID
inner join gloffice glo on ga.GLOffice = glo.GLOfficeID
WHERE gn.GLNat IN ('11001','11002','11003','11005','11007','11011','11016','11019','11020','11021','11022','11024','11025','11026','11027','11032','11033',
'11034','11035','11036','11037','11040','11041','11042','11043','11044','11050','11051','11052','11053','11190','11199','11201','11202','11203','11204',
'11205','11206','11207','11301','11603','11700','11705','11801','11802','11803','11804','11806','11807','11808','11809','11901')--,'22001')
AND gd.PostDate <=  @Yesterday
GROUP BY
glo.GLValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub-table that give the sums for each PostDate and GLValue similar to above but also grouped on PostDate, then join that to your select above, e.g.

inner join gloffice glo on ga.GLOffice = glo.GLOfficeID
inner join ( ... new grouped select here ...) gs on gs.GLValue = glo.GlValue and gs.PostDate < gd.PostDate

Now you should be able to sum the gs values:

, Sum(gs.Credit) as Credit
, Sum(gs.Debit) as Debit

etc.